# sorting nested lists of numbers and alphabets

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I am working with python 
I have a nested list
`[[ram,67][Sam,56][don,67][tom,78][Raul,54]]`
I want to sort this list according to number and for same numbers according to alphabet

I have tried this doesn't helps

```py
import numpy as np
students = np.array[['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2], ['Akriti', 41], ['Harsh', 39]]
sortedStudents = np.sorted(students,lambda x:x[1])
print(sortedStudents)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the regular python 'sorted' to perform this task with a regular list as well

```
students = [['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2], ['Akriti', 41], 
            ['Harsh', 39]]

# Sort by list index 1, then index 0
sortedStudents = sorted(students, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
print(sortedStudents)
```

output:

```
[['Tina', 37.2], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Harry', 37.21], ['Harsh', 39], ['Akriti', 41]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this task using basic python functions, But if really want to use numpy Then -

There are some errors in your code.

1. `np.array()` can't take values like this. It is function so `students = np.array([['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2], ['Akriti', 41], ['Harsh', 39]])`
2. use `argsort()` as there is no `sorted()` in numpy.
3. `np.sort()` will not give desired result.

So your final code should be:

```
import numpy as np
students = np.array([['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2], ['Akriti', 41], ['Harsh', 39]])
students[students[:,column].argsort()]
```

sort by column 0 returns

```
array([['Akriti', '41'],
   ['Berry', '37.21'],
   ['Harry', '37.21'],
   ['Harsh', '39'],
   ['Tina', '37.2']], dtype='<U6')
```

sort by column 1 returns

```
array([['Tina', '37.2'],
   ['Harry', '37.21'],
   ['Berry', '37.21'],
   ['Harsh', '39'],
   ['Akriti', '41']], dtype='<U6')
```

Hope this will help.